# Do I need more than 2 dimensions to "draw"/realize any abstract graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

**The question** from my current exercise sheet I'm trying to solve is

> What is the minimal $n$ such that given any finite abstract graph $(V,E,\varphi)$ there exists a topological realization in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

where an *abstract graph* is defined as

> a triple $(V,E,\varphi)$ such that $V\neq\emptyset$, $E$ is a set, $\varphi:E\to\{W\subset V~:~ |W|\in\{1,2\}\}$

and a *topogolical graph* is defined as

> a pair $(V,E)$ with $\emptyset\neq V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $E\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
>
> 1. $E\cap V=\emptyset$
> 2. each component of $E$ is a bounded $1$-D submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$
> 3. each component has its endpoints lying in $V$
> 4. every bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ intersects only finitely many components of $E$.

(A topological graph $T$ is a realization of an abstract graph $G$ if the underlying abstract graph of $T$ is isomorphic to $G$.)

---

**My attempt** looks like this (shortened):

$n=1$ is obviously too small. But for $n=2$ this seems to work, because I can check 1.-4. of the definition above like this:

1. I always can lead the edge arount any vertex in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
2. I always can find a path from one point to another in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
3. I just define the endpoints of such path/edge to be the vertices.
4. I always can lead the edges such that they don't touch each other in an infinite number of points because the finiteness of the graph in question.

So if I'm understanding this correctly, this definition of a topological graph doesn't care about intersection of the edges. I'm a bit sceptical of my solution because the next sub-exercise starts with "*Now let $G$ and $G'$ be two topological graphs in $\mathbb{R}^3$ [...]*" followed by a question that doesn't seem to rely on the dimension at all which in turn suggests that I need $n=3$ to be sure of the bare existence of a topological realization. (Might be our instructor messing with us...)

What can go wrong in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that I'm missing?

Hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exercise does care about the intersection of edges. See "2. each component of $E$ is a bounded 1-D submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that is homeomorphic to $(0,1)$". If edges intersect, the component containing the intersecting edges will not be a manifold and will not be homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. So in order to actually rule out the dimension $2$ case, you need to prove that there exists a graph that cannot be realized topologically in $\mathbb{R}^2$ without having at least one pair of edges intersect (for your counterexample, think about a graph with a lot of edges!). So how many dimensions must we add in order to solve this issue of intersections?

Graphs that can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are called "planar" graphs.

Comment: You are right, I didn't spot that. A counterexample should be a complete graph with 5 vertices. Three dimensions let me circumvent any intersection. Thank you!

Comment: @Piwi BiP(3,3) and K(5) both, and IIRC they're both necessary-and-sufficient for nonplanarity.

Comment: There is a nice result, Casson and Gordon, I think,  that any embedding of $K_7$ in 3-space contains a knot, It is not always easy to find it! Any embedding of $K_6$ in 3-space contains a link, and that is easier to find.